Evidence of composition of water molecules?
What was the earliest evidence that led to the conclusion that water molecules comprise 2 atoms of hydrogen and one of oxygen?
Earliest scientists couldn't see atoms so how did they deduce the ratio?

A candidate for migration to Stack Exchange - History of Science and Mathematics

Nobody can see atoms despite the news claims. All measurements for molecular compositions are indirect. This question has a well known history, did you search?

AFM is quite direct, not seeing, but touching molecules.

These are really multiple problems: developing a theory of atoms, and one that describes how these are combined into molecules (compounds). The development of electrolysis allowed detailed investigations into the compound structure of substances including isolation of elemental compounds. There are posts on this in history of sci and math SE. Apparently hydrogen and oxygen gas were known already by then.

see also: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/how-was-the-composition-and-structure-of-water-determined#:%7E:text=1805%3A%20Gay%2DLussac%20and%20Humboldt,of%20oxygen%20(by%20volume)

In 1800, Cavendish discovered that water wasn't an element but rather a compound by burning hydrogen and oxygen to produce water. He enclosed hydrogen and oxygen in a tube and combusted it to give water vapour which condensed on the sides. He also measured the mass of hydrogen and oxygen and found it to be equal to mass of water. Lavoisier later reproduced the experiment and determined the name of one of gases which we now know as hydrogen.
Later Johan Ritter confirmed the ratio of hydrogen to oxygen in water by doing an electrolysis experiment on water (1800). He then measured the amount of oxygen and hydrogen produced by measuring the volume of the gases.
This might be helpful

The mole is a recent unit, defined during the 20th century. It was not known during Cavendish times.

@Maurice But one of the key observations that led to the concept of mole was that gases combine in integer ratios of volumes. The led to the basic idea of the mole.
